# How can I make OS X forget SSH passphrase when I close lid/after a certain amount of time?

Tags: macos, mac, ssh

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.3 and openssh, basically I have the inverse problem to most people in that I want to make my laptop automatically lock the keychain (specifically my private key) every time I close the lid or just more frequently.

I can't seem to find any way of setting this option in the keychain app. Does anyone have any idea on how I can configure this? It's just way too relaxed at the moment.

Comment: Are you storing your SSH key integrated with a Keychain, or are you using no OS X specific SSH functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Keychain Access*, right-click the keychain in question, and select *Change Settings for Keychain "Name"*. Check *Lock after… minutes of inactivity* and *Lock when sleeping*.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The screenshot makes this answer a winner :)

Answer (score 1):

KeychainAccess > Preferences in the General tab tick the option
Show keychain status in menubar

this will put an icon in the menu bar that has options to lock the keychain.